# T-SQL, Multiple Updates in a scheduled job

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-performance

I've been developing a query to be used as a scheduled job. To make it short, I'm to make some specific calculations on a table, and update a few columns (like STATE) according to the calculation results.

A sample (as currently how it is) could be demonstrated as follows :

---

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET STATE = 1
WHERE {some condition}

UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET STATE = 2
WHERE {some condition}

UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET STATE = 3, SOME_OTHER_COLUMN={value}
WHERE {some condition}

WHILE(some condition)

BEGIN
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET STATE = 4, SOME_OTHER_COLUMN={value}

WHERE {some condition}

END
```

---

What I've tried to demonstrate above is, the flow of the query. As It can be seen above, I'm updating a single table multiple times, mostly setting a single state column with different values depending on different conditions.

I also had to use a while loop, instead of a cursor (because of poor performance), because it was needed to update the data in this table with small groups depending on those conditions.

Assuming all the query is wrapped in a transaction and a try-catch block.

And finally, here's my question :
Since this is gonna be a scheduled job to be executed at night, the performance is not the top priority for me. However, i couldnt figure out how to make the same operation with a somewhat more cleaner and more efficient (performance wise) query. I'm in need of some advices. 
Please note that, {some condition} areas hold subqueries with EXISTS functionality. So the original code looks far more messy than this. Thanks in advance.
--Ozan

Comment: A general note, you can use a `CASE` statement in the `SET` clause... but whether or not this would simplify your query depends on details that aren't specified yet.

Comment: Hello, I've thought of using the CASE statement aswell. However, those areas ive denoted with {some condition}, usually looks up to the same table with multiple subqueries (filtering the data) and matching it with the outer query with EXISTS -...- WHERE outerQueryTable.Id = innerSummaryQueryTable.Id So, im not sure that would be a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is small enough, then multiple queries will not hurt.

Even if it is considerably large to where the `WHERE` clause of the query works efficiently because of indexes, you may be OK.

You could consolidate the queries - if the `WHERE` clauses are the same, then you can put those together.

IMO, the easier the code is to read, the easier it is to maintain. If you're not getting major performance gains then there's really no point in consolidating.

Efficiency of a query is measured in the amount of resources it consumes, not how nicely consolidated it is or how complex it looks.  You may be better off looking at execution plans and figuring out any structural changes or indexes you need on the table.

The biggest thing that catches my eye is that you tried a `CURSOR` and now have changed it to a `WHILE` loop.

You will find that Set-based operations are much more conducive to database work than cursors.

**EDIT based on OPs comment**

Since the table is expected to fill up quite fast, you should do a load test. Load the table up with a ton of test data (let's say one years worth) and see how your queries perform.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately the table will be filled with data quite fast, as soon as it goes live. Consolidation of the queries does not seem like an options aswell, since the conditions are fairly different from eachother.

Comment: Could you please be more clear with the statement "You will find that Set-based operations are much more conducive to database work than cursors.". You mean replacing Cursor with a While was a bad idea? Thanks

Comment: To be more clear, I'm not inspecting the whole table row-by-row with that WHILE loop. I'm simply getting a distinct value of a FK ID, and updating batches of rows with that ID. Simply like, UPDATE X WHERE ID=@whileVariable. So in short, say the table got 1M rows, my while will loop at most 10 times, not 1M times.